# Performing 2 JOINs on same table

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, sum, inner-join

I am using Standard SQL in Google BigQuery. I'm trying to list the number of tlc yellow trips from Greenwich Village North to Greenwich Village South (These are the zone_id's in taxi_zone_geom table) in December 2018 and total amount. The zone_id's correspond with the pickup_location_id and dropoff_location_id in the tlc_yellow_trips_2018 table.

taxi_zone_geom table:

```
Row zone_id zone_name   borough zone_geom
1   1   Newark Airport  EWR POLY
2   3   Allerton/Pelham Gardens Bronx   POLYGON((-73.8...
```

trips_2018 table

```
Row vendor_id   pickup_datetime dropoff_datetime    passenger_count trip_distance   rate_code   store_and_fwd_flag  payment_type    fare_amount extra   mta_tax tip_amount  tolls_amount    imp_surcharge   total_amount    pickup_location_id  dropoff_location_id 
1   2   2018-05-06T21:13:05 2018-05-06T21:35:33 1   9.83    1   N   1   29  0.5 0.5 6.06    0   0.3 36.36   138 65  
2   1   2018-05-06T21:59:42 2018-05-06T22:25:17 1   10.7    1   N   1   32  0.5 0.5 6.65    0   0.3 39.95   138 25  
3   1   2018-05-06T23:54:05 2018-05-07T00:19:30 2   9.6 1   N   1   30.5    0.5 0.5 6.35    0   0.3 38.15   114 116
```

This works fine:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pickup_datetime) AS Month,
COUNT(*) AS Dec_trips_GVNorth_to_GVSouth,
SUM(total_amount) as total,
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018` AS t 
LEFT JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` AS g ON t.pickup_location_id=g.zone_id WHERE g.zone_name='Greenwich Village North'
GROUP BY Month HAVING Month=12
```

However, I need to link to the drop_off by joining the same table, which I try to do using a secondary join as below:

```
LEFT JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` AS g2 ON t.dropoff_location_id=g2.zone_id WHERE g2.zone_name='Greenwich Village South'
```

This results in an error "Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LEFT at [7:1]"

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this as two joins, with filtering in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Dec_trips_GVNorth_to_GVSouth,
    SUM(total_amount) as total
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018` AS t 
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` AS g1 
    ON t.pickup_location_id = g1.zone_id 
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.taxi_zone_geom` AS g2
    ON t.dropoff_location_id = g2.zone_id 
WHERE 
    g1.zone_name = 'Greenwich Village North'
    AND g2.zone_name = 'Greenwich Village South'
    AND pickup_datetime >= date '2018-12-01'
    AND pickup_datetime >= date '2019-01-01'
```

Notes:

- Since you want to actually filter on the pickup / dropoff locations, use `INNER JOIN`s, not `LEFT JOIN`s
- I don't see the need for an explicit `GROUP BY` clause, nor for a `HAVING` clause: you can filter on the target month directly in the `WHERE` clause, using half open intervals and literal dates
- If the table has data for 2018 only, as its name suggests, then the filter condition on the upper date range is superfluous

Comment: Thank you! You shared valuable information on top of fully answering my question.